# How to print out the value that subprocess prints with C#?

Tags: c#, subprocess, interprocess

As is asked in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304072/print-out-the-output-of-os-popen-without-buffering-in-python), I can use Python's subprocess.Popen() function to print out the value from running ruby's code.

```
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ["ruby", "/Users/smcho/Desktop/testit.rb"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print line, 
    sys.stdout.flush() 
p.wait()
```

How can I do the same thing with C#? How can one print the value what the subprocess prints out?

Comment: You'll want to look into redirecting stdout from a `Process` object.  The accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642147/redirect-the-output-stdout-stderr-of-a-child-process-to-the-output-window-in-v) shows how you can do it asynchronously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to redirect stdout when spawning the child process; MSDN has a complete example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

(from MSDN):

```
 // Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("ruby", "/Users/smcho/Desktop/testit.rb");
psi.RedirectStandardOuput = true;W    
Process proc = new Process(psi);
proc.Start();
StreamReader stdout = proc.StandardOutput;
string line;
while ((line = stdout.ReadLine()) != null)
   Console.WriteLine(line);
```